# Problem when binding to 'formGroup' on Angular11

Tags: angular, typescript, formgroups, angular11

I'm developing a Angular11 project for homework, and I'm trying to save data to my Cloud Firestore with a form using some bootstrap, but when I launch the app, it says the following:

error NG8002: Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'.

```
  <form class="mt-4" [formGroup]="createProducto" (ngSubmit)="agregarProducto()">
                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/components/add-productos.component.ts:9:16
    9   templateUrl: '../views/add-productos.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AddProductosComponent.
```

Here is where I have the problem

`<form class="mt-4" [formGroup]="createProducto" (ngSubmit)="agregarProducto()">`

Here are my imports on my component:

```
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ProductoService } from '../services/producto.service'
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
```

And here is where I create the "createProducto: FormGroup"m which should work with no problems

```
export class AddProductosComponent implements OnInit {
  createProducto: FormGroup
  submitted = false
```

I have already tried some things people have posted here, but none of them work for me.

Comment: Did you `import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';` in your app.module.ts?

Comment: Yes I did, everything seems to be correct

Comment: You will have to import `ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule` in your `AddProductosComponent`'s module as well

Comment: Now it shows no error, but the component is not working :/ Thankyou man, at least my first error is gone

Comment: Double check for the imports, and try restarting the app.

Comment: Yeah, now ir works fine, thankyou :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the error by importing ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule in my AddProductosComponent.